# Powershell - gather all .psd files in the same directory

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a folder tree with random names.
In the subdirectories I have multiples files.
I'm trying to copy all ".psd" files in the "_PSD" directory in order to gather them in the same folder.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnuvL.jpg

I've managed to list the related files using the following powershell code :

```
ls "D:\work\76063_000\tmp" -Recurse | where {$_.Name -match "\b.*.psd" } | format-table
```

How should I do to copy the listed files in _PSD ? 
Remeber that I don't want to keep the subdirectories inside _PSD.
The goal is to copy all psd files directly inside _PSD.

Many Thanks !

Comment: How do you plan to handle naming conflicts? If the files are presently in multiple directories and you're copying them all into one, you potentially have multiple files with the same name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested as I don't have Windows available at the moment to test with. There should be a way to skip the `where-object` and use `-exclude` in `get-childitem` but IIRC there's some flakiness with it depending on your powershell version.

```
get-childitem -recurse -filter *.psd |
    where-object {$_.fullname -notlike "*\_PSD*"} |
    copy-item -destination D:\work\76063_000\tmp\_PSD
```

Linebreaks added for readability.

Comment: +1. IIRC, `-exclude` only checks the filename/foldername, so to use that he would have to do it like `get-childitem -exclude "_PSD" | ? { $_.PSIsContainer } | get-childitem -recurse -filter *.psd | copy....`